# TFS - Obligatory code review before check-in is applied to branch

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfvc, tfs-code-review

I want to be able to review every check-in before the code is applied to the branch, is it possible in TFS?

I know we can add check-in policy to force code-review but this is applied before the check-in and not after. 
I'm looking for a way that would not block the existing flow.

Thanks

Comment: What you're asking for is exactly what the TFVC code review workflow already does. It uses shelvesets to accomplish it. Code isn't checked in, it's shelved.

Comment: What do you mean block the existing flow? Provide the details of "existing flow"

Comment: @DanielMann And if I want to lock a specific branch so that only the accepted check-ins by resquest review can be checked-in how can I do that?

Comment: No built-in feature can do that, you can just grant specific members (e.g. dev manager) the corresponding permission (e.g. check in) for that branch, then just these members can check in/merge to specific branch.

Answer (score 4):

TFS supports two source control systems that each have their own workflow based on established practices:

1. **TFVC** - This is a server based source control system that supports Code Reviews using Shelved changes prior to check-in. As @daniel Mann stated it works exactly as you described.
2. **Git** - This is a distributed source control system and uses Pull Requests to facilite reviews of Merges. Since all work is done on a separate branch, you review the proposed pulls of code from one branch to another.

It sounds like you are using TFVC so the existing Code Review model would fit your purpose.